# What is the typical time period between peer reviews being completed and editorial decision?

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

My question pertains to article submission waiting times.

How long, your experiences, is the period of time between a journal receiving completed peer reviews back on a paper (as indicated by the online system), and a decision being issued to the authour?

My particular case: I have submitted to a large geography journal, and can see that peer reviews have been in for a month, in which time my manuscript is shown as "awaiting ed decision". Advice as to if/when to pester the editors would be useful to me.

Thanks greatly

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE! We have [a canonical question for journal workflows](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/4140). The "editorial decision" stage there is said to take about a week. A month seems a bit long. Are sure that *all* reviews are in and that the editor is not waiting for another one?

Comment: Canonical indeed! Yes, the ed manager said a while back that they were waiting for a final reviewer, after which it switched to "awaiting ed decision."

Comment: so you would recommend a query after 1 month?
thanks

Comment: Editors can be swamped and may simply have a lot on their plate. Do you have a senior colleague who has published in this particular journal before, who you could ask? It appears to me that you could send off a short and polite inquiry, but then, all of us here don't know the specific journal, nor the specific editor.

Comment: Sadly I don't - I will do as you suggest, and send the managing ed a minor inquiry. Thanks a lot